# Seleccionar todos los checkbox de los nodos hijos de un nodo en un JTree

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero dar permisos según los perfiles de usuarios para ello estoy trabajando con JTree en el cual un nodo tiene 1 o más hijos, a su vez el nodo hijo puede tener su propios hijos y asi sucesivamente hasta un 5to nivel de hijos.

El árbol queda de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi Consulta**

Quiero que al seleccionar un nodo padre todos los nodos internos se seleccionen.
Mi otra duda es si al seleccionar cada nodo puedo formar un arreglo con el listado de las posiciones de los nodos seleccionados para poder guardar esos datos en una base de datos.

Para la creación del árbol he usado el siguiente código

```
public class TreePermisos extends JFrame {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreePermisos tp = new TreePermisos();
        tp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tp.setSize(850, 500);
        tp.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TreePermisos() {
        super();
            JTree tree = new JTree(getRootNode()) {
          @Override
          public boolean isPathEditable(TreePath path) {
            Object comp = path.getLastPathComponent();
            if (comp instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
              DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) comp;
              Object userObject = node.getUserObject();
              if (userObject instanceof TrueFalseTreeNodeData) {
                return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        };
        QuestionCellRenderer renderer = new QuestionCellRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        QuestionCellEditor editor = new QuestionCellEditor();
        tree.setCellEditor(editor);
        tree.setEditable(true);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(tree);
        getContentPane().add(jsp);
    }

    protected MutableTreeNode getRootNode() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root,nivel1,nivel2,nivel3,nivel4;
        TrueFalseTreeNodeData rootT;

        rootT=new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Seleccionar Todo");      
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rootT);

        //1.RRHH
        //2.Operaciones        
        //3.Contabilidad
        nivel1=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Contabilidad"));
            //3.1
            nivel2=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Fichero"));
            nivel1.add(nivel2);             
            //3.2
            nivel2=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Transacciones")); 
                //3.2.1
                nivel3=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Trabajador Eventual"));
                    //3.2.1.1
                    nivel4=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Pagos por Realizar"));
                    nivel3.add(nivel4);
                    //3.2.1.2
                    nivel4=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Pagos Realizados"));
                    nivel3.add(nivel4);
                    //3.2.1.3
                    nivel4=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Descuentos del Trabajador"));
                    nivel3.add(nivel4);
                nivel2.add(nivel3);
                //3.2.2
                nivel3=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new TrueFalseTreeNodeData("Trabajador Fijo")); 
                nivel2.add(nivel3);                
            nivel1.add(nivel2);
        root.add(nivel1); 
        //4.Presupuestos
        return root;
    }
}
```

Para que el nodo tenga el checkbox

```
class TrueFalseTreeNodeData {

    protected final String value;
    protected boolean booleanValue;

    public TrueFalseTreeNodeData(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
  
    public boolean isBooleanValue() {
        return booleanValue;
    }

    public void setBooleanValue(boolean booleanValue) {
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
    }
       
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return value + " = " + booleanValue;
    }
}
```

```
class QuestionCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    protected TrueFalseTreeNodeData nodeData;

    public QuestionCellEditor() {
        super(new JCheckBox());
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
        JCheckBox editor = null;
        nodeData = getQuestionFromValue(value);
        if (nodeData != null) {
            editor = (JCheckBox) (super.getComponent());
            editor.setText(nodeData.getValue());
            editor.setSelected(nodeData.isBooleanValue());
        }
        return editor;
    }

    public static TrueFalseTreeNodeData getQuestionFromValue(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
            Object userObject = node.getUserObject();
            if (userObject instanceof TrueFalseTreeNodeData) {
                return (TrueFalseTreeNodeData) userObject;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
  @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        JCheckBox editor = (JCheckBox) (super.getComponent());
        nodeData.setBooleanValue(editor.isSelected());
        return nodeData;
    }
}
```

```
class QuestionCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    protected JCheckBox checkBoxRenderer = new JCheckBox();

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
        boolean hasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
            Object userObject = node.getUserObject();
            if (userObject instanceof TrueFalseTreeNodeData) {
              TrueFalseTreeNodeData question = (TrueFalseTreeNodeData) userObject;
              prepareQuestionRenderer(question, selected);
              return checkBoxRenderer;
            }
        }
        return super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded,
            leaf, row, hasFocus);
    }

    protected void prepareQuestionRenderer(TrueFalseTreeNodeData tfq, boolean selected) {
        checkBoxRenderer.setText(tfq.getValue());
        checkBoxRenderer.setSelected(tfq.isBooleanValue());
        if (selected) {
            checkBoxRenderer.setForeground(getTextSelectionColor());
            checkBoxRenderer.setBackground(getBackgroundSelectionColor());
        } else {
            checkBoxRenderer.setForeground(getTextNonSelectionColor());
            checkBoxRenderer.setBackground(getBackgroundNonSelectionColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en muchos componentes de Swing que contienen un modelo de datos, la opción para modificar sin meterse en tanto problema es reemplazar los elementos agregados en el modelo de datos.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(i);
TrueFalseTreeNodeData childTreeNodeData = (TrueFalseTreeNodeData) childNode.getUserObject();
childTreeNodeData.setBooleanValue(true);
childNode.setUserObject(childTreeNodeData);
```

Esto lo puedes lograr con llamadas reentrantes a la función para reemplazar cada subárbol con uno nuevo con los valores cambiados.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(i);
if(!childNode.isLeaf()){
    updateChilds(childNode);
}
```

Si deseas ahondar en más detalles te hice [un artículo al respecto](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/swing-y-jtree-seleccionar-hijos-al-dar-click-en-checkbox/) en mi blog, y allí mismo hallarás la liga el código completo.

Comment: Agradezco el artículo que hiciste aprendí bastante con ello, he corrido el programa en Netbeans 8.2 con java 8 así que he tenido que realizar un downgrade al proyecto que compartes en tu github, no se si es por el dowgrade pero al seleccionar un nodo padre no se seleccionan los nodos hijos visualmente pero si se muestra que los nodos hijos cambian a true en la salida por pantalla ``System.out.println("cn->"+childNode)``; lo curioso es que si doy check en **seleccionar todo** si se realiza el cambio visual y bueno me faltaría trabajar la opción para deseleccionar los checkbox.

Comment: es extraño a mí sí me selecciona todos los hijos, tal ves podrías intentar mandar la llamada recursiva al hilo gráfico mediante swingUtilities

Comment: Disculpa, estaba en otra cosa no te entendí bien ``llamada recursiva al hilo gráfico mediante swingUtilities``